# Linux Mint 17.3 doesn't detect Win10 partitions

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, windows, partition-table

I've installed Win10 and I want to install Linux Mint 17.3. When I'm installing Linux Mint, it doesn't see Win10 partitions. It's just showing whole disk size.

[image: Linux Mint 17.3 installation window.]

By the way, I'm installing Linux Mint in the same OS mode as Win10. What I should do that Linux Mint would start detecting Windows?

Comment: Have you booted the Mint in UEFI/EFI mode?

Comment: I've tried in both ways, the same issue

Answer (score 0):

What is the first drive when you boot Linux Mint from USB and what is where your Windows is installed doesn't have to be the same. Your windows is far more likely to have been installed on `/dev/sdb` (an SDD?) and /dev/sda is indeed completely free.

Check `/dev/sdb` if it has your Windows partitions you can just proceed with using (some) of the free space on `/dev/sda`.

If something goes wrong you can just restore `/dev/sdb` from your backup. If you didn't make a backup before starting to try and install Linux Mint, you correctly estimated the value of its (i.e. Win10) availability at what it is worth.

Comment: I think that Windows is in /dev/sda and Linux Mint boot USB is /dev/sdb. Now I'm trying to install Ubuntu 15.10, this os finds Windows well.